# Grails: I need to measure the time it takes to create a graph in a grails application

Tags: grails

I have a view that `<g:render>`s a template and the template has a `<g:each>` statement that
creates an image which the src of the image is a `${createLink}` call to a controller that creates the image (plotted graph).  I need to total the time of creating the set of images. Any ideas on how to do that?  Also in the view is a called to Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater to update the graphs every 10 seconds.  Basically I have the following in the template:

```
<g:each in "${list}" var="l">
     <img src="${createLink(controller:'fooController', params: [blah:blah], action:"controllerAction')}"
</g:each>
```

I tried doing it at the action method side but each call is a different Thread and I need the total time of all images created.  I tried measuring before the `<g:each>` and after but that didn't work because of the Threads.

How can I do this?

If my action method returns a time can I access it from within the `<g:each>`.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably must be measured from client side. And this can be easily done by using just **Firebug** for Firefox, it shows you all information about current page, including total time of loading it.

Comment: I need to collect the information on the server side.  Basically, I want to know the performance of rendering the graph when multiple clients hit the page....thanks...

Comment: It can be measured only on client-side. btw, if you need to measure it automatically you can use javascript for this